# how do I update the date type column?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
update answers a1 
   set a1.FilingDate=(
                       select date_sub( a2.FilingDate
                                       ,Interval 1000 Year) as FilingDate
                       from answers a2 
                       where Year(a2.FilingDate)>=3000
                     )
where Year(a1.FilingDate)>=3000
```

but it gives me the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'update
>   answers a1 set a1.FilingDate=( select
>   date_sub(a2.FilingDate,Interval 10' at
>   line 1

Can anyone tell me about the issue and its solution?

Comment: It may sound silly, but if you want to use the sub-query, try putting double parentheses around it: 'SET a1.FilingDate = ((SELECT ...))'.  If that works, then the first (outer) parentheses enclose a list of values (one value), and the second (inner) parentheses enclose a SELECT statement to be executed.  If it doesn't work on MySQL, I won't be surprised - but I do know of a DBMS where that is the required notation and approximately the logic used to explain it.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler: Does assigning a list to a single value really work in that DBMS (DB2/Informix?). If so, which value from the list is chosen? Note, the DBMS has no way of knowing if the subquery returns one or 10'000 results before parsing.

Comment: @lexu: well, what I meant is that Informix (IDS) allows: `SET (a, b, c) = ((SELECT v1, v2, v3 FROM SomeWhere WHERE ...))` as a notation.  It will execute the sub-select for each row satisfied by the outer WHERE clause (the one on the UPDATE as a whole).  If the sub-query returns more than one row of data, you get a run-time error.  But, as the notation shows, you can assign three values from one sub-query that returns three values.  It may be no help; it may be completely specific to Informix.  That is, in part, why it is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Thanks for the explanation. I was hoping to learn, thank you for that comment!

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery can return more than one value per row in A1, MySQL doesn't know which value from A2 it should pick!

Me thinks your query could also read:

```
update answers a1 
   set a1.FilingDate=date_sub( a1.FilingDate,Interval 1000 Year)
where Year(a1.FilingDate)>=3000
```

**CAVEAT** try this on a backup!